# Stack trace for sql query execution? (Zend Framework)

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there a way to get the stack trace for each sql query using the db profiler?

I'm using the profiler like so:

> foreach($profiler->getQueryProfiles()
>   as $query) {
>
> }

Which is fine as I can get elapsed seconds, actual query etc but I want to know where this query was called from so I need the last 3 or 4 items in the stack trace.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extend Zend_Db_Profiler and use `debug_backtrace()` in the queryEnd method.